# How to customize the period in cohort analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am performing a cohort analysis and able to get it working with periods of 1 month, but I am trying to customize the cohort analysis to use x month periods. Basically, if a user transacts once within 12 months of their cohort they should be considered retained. I am currently following this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-introduction-to-cohort-analysis-in-python-a2cbbd8460ea), but this line is giving me an issue

```
df_cohort = df.groupby(['cohort', 'order_month']) \
              .agg(n_customers=('CustomerID', 'nunique')) \
              .reset_index(drop=False)
df_cohort['period_number'] = (df_cohort.order_month - df_cohort.cohort).apply(attrgetter('n'))
```

Based on the period number the period would be each subsequent month, but I'm trying to group 12 month increments into 1 period.

Happy to clarify the question or provide any more details

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column 'year' and then group by this column instead of 'cohort'(month).

The column 'year' can be extracted from 'cohort'(month).

Comment: what if I wanted to do like 6 months or 8 months?

Comment: The same. You can add another column to indicate that these month belong to different group. Then use group by.